# Conditional Formatting on Google Sheets depending on cell in other sheet

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

So I have one sheet that's a timeline, with the first column being an ascending list of dates and the second being a description of the event that happens on that date.

Another sheet has a cell with a specific date.

I would like the cell on the first column of the first sheet whose date is the date on that second sheet's cell to be formatted. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the second sheet has a date in cell A1, then the first column of the first sheet should have conditional formatting "Value is equal to... " `=indirect("Sheet2!A1")`

The use of `indirect` is necessary because otherwise conditional formatting rules cannot refer to other sheets.

[image: example]