# Google Sheets - Conditional Formating - using ISBLANK to reference a cell in a different sheet

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm new to Google Sheets so would appreciate some assistance as my research has been unsucessful.

I have created a schedule with peoples names filling time slots. I have duplicated the sheet for the same layout to be able to create a print out that shows which time slots are available using just colours so as not to distribute the names listed. To do this I want to use conditional formating and show a colour in the cells (time slots) not yet filled.

I thought that the custom formula needs be something like... conditional formating for cell E14 on sheet "Schedule Printout"... ISBLANK('Schedule!E14') but this doesn't work.

Screen grab of the Conditional Formating dialog box[image]

I have tried several different variations. If you have any ideas please can you let me know?

Thank you

James Webb
[jameswebb.uk](https://www.jameswebb.uk)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Condition Formating, how to highlight a cell when it dosn't include text in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51449598/condition-formating-how-to-highlight-a-cell-when-it-dosnt-include-text-in-a-li)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional Formatting from another sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735025/conditional-formatting-from-another-sheet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works

```
=INDIRECT("Schedule!E14")=""
```

I believe you have to use INDIRECT in conditional formatting when you want to reference a different sheet/tab.

Comment: That works, thank you. Is there a way to copy this to all the cells to link with the cooresponding cell? i.e. When the print out sheet is B14 can it automatically put =INDIRECT("Schedule!B14")="" etc

I just want to copy and paste this to each of the cells.